# ADF V2 Azure IR for copy from FTP

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

As per documentation of ADF V2, Azure IR should be used for public network data movement. I have a requirement to copy the file from FTP to Blob. The article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-ftp redirects to Self-hosted runtime than Azure IR.

To copy from FTP whether Self-hosted runtime needs to be used? Can't we use Azure IR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure IR. And for that case, to simplify the configuration, you can use the default Azure IR which means you don't need to really create an IR and associate in linked service, in other word, simply remove the connectVia section from the [FTP linked service samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-ftp#linked-service-properties).